# Is Boost.Locale part of official boost release?

Tags: c++, boost, localization

I don't see Boost.Locale in the version boost_1_46_1 that I downloaded.
If not what is the proper way to build an individual boost library ( those that are not header only )? 
I could download from here http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/index.html but I would rather
not have to re-build the entire boost

Answer (score 3):

[Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html) is now part of the official Boost release, in version 1.48. It took a while, but it's formally out now.

Comment: Bolas. Thanks. Any idea(s) on the second part of my question?

Answer (score 2):

It was [accepted](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/218369) into Boost but have not been released as part of Boost yet.

How to build?

See: http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/building_boost_locale.html